# Remove oldest duplicates and keep latest duplicate by time stamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a query as follows:

```
;WITH Duplicates AS 
    (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ChannelName, SerialNumber, ReadingDate ORDER BY ChannelName) AS Rownumber
        FROM [Staging].[UriData]        
    )       
    DELETE FROM Duplicates WHERE Rownumber > 1
    --AND ROWNUMBER >=< ???
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

This works great and finds the duplicates in the table. However, the table is frequently updated with corrected data.

By the time the query has run, there could have been three or more updates.

This means I want to delete all but the latest records. There is a timestamp field in the table, that denotes when the latest insert happened. I am assuming I should use this field to determine which is the latest row, and any that are not the highest row number, delete them. Is this the correct approach?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can use `timestamp` column with `ROW_NUMBER()` & you don't need to use *recursion* hint as your `CTE` has not any recursion level.

```
;WITH Duplicates AS  (
       SELECT *, 
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ChannelName, SerialNumber, ReadingDate ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS Rownumber
       FROM [Staging].[UriData]        
 ) 

DELETE d
FROM Duplicates d
WHERE Rownumber > 1;
```

Comment: Of course DESC! I'm trying to over complicate things as usual! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE older
FROM Staging.UriData older
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1
   FROM Staging.UriData newer
   WHERE newer.ChannelName = older.older
      and newer.SerialNumber = older.SerialNumber
      and newer.ReadingDate = older.ReadingDate
      and newer.timestamp > older.timestamp
)
```